# remove empty Arrays from multidimensional Array generated with simplexml

Tags: php, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I have an xml file with the following structure:

```
<categories>
  <category>
    <id>3</id>
    <title><![CDATA[Testname]]></title>
    <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
    <keywords><![CDATA[]]></keywords>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
  </category>
</categories>
```

Now I'm loading this file and creating an array of it:

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_file( 'categories.xml', null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xmlData), true);
```

That generates me the following Result (print_r Output):

```
Array
(
  [@attributes] => Array
    (
      [version] => 1.0
    )

  [categories] => Array
    (
      [category] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
            (
              [id] => 3
              [title] => Testname
              [text] => Array
                (
                )

              [keywords] => Array
                (
                )

              [description] => Array
                (
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Here is my question, how could I remove those empty arrays? I tried it with array Filter, but this didn't work. (I need the keys, but they should be empty)

I know there would be a way, in my next step where I'm renaming the array keys as needed, i could check for empty arrays in the foreach loop, but I think there is an easier way, because every field (except id) could be empty in the xml file.

```
foreach($array['categories']['category'] as $key => $category){
  $results[$key]['id'] = $category['id'];
  $results[$key]['headline'] = $category['title'];
  $results[$key]['content'] = $category['text'];
  $results[$key]['metaKeywords'] = $category['keywords'];
  $results[$key]['metaDescription'] = $category['description'];
}
```

Does someone has an idea, what i could do after the json_decode? Or is there an easier way for all I'm trying to accomplish here?

Thanks!

Comment: So you first iterate over `categories` to remove empty values, and then again iterate over `categories` to create `$results`. Why do you need to do it __tiwce__?

Answer (score 2):

Every time I see someone use that `json_decode(json_encode())` hack, it makes me sad. You don't need to turn the SimpleXML object into an array to loop over it, just read [the usage examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

If you loop over the SimpleXML object directly, you will never get those arrays, so will never need to remove them:

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_file('categories.xml'); // LIBXML_NOCDATA is NOT needed
foreach($xmlData->categories->category as $key => $category){
  $results[$key]['id'] = (string)$category->id;
  $results[$key]['headline'] = (string)$category->title;
  $results[$key]['content'] = (string)$category->text;
  $results[$key]['metaKeywords'] = (string)$category->keywords;
  $results[$key]['metaDescription'] = (string)$category->description;
}
```

The `(string)` tells SimpleXML you want the text content of a particular element (including CDATA), and will give you an empty string for the empty elements.

Comment: I've tried it like you suggested, but I'm not getting a full array. Please take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229159/foreach-loop-over-simplexmlelement-not-working-only-1-element-as-result

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work. [PHP code demo](https://eval.in/764233)

```
<?php
$result=Array
(

  "categories" => Array
    (
      "category" => Array
        (
          0 => Array
            (
              "id" => 3,
              "title" => "Testname",
              "text" => Array
                (
                ),

              "keywords" => Array
                (
                ),

              "description" => Array
                (
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
$results=array();
foreach($result['categories']['category'] as $key => $category){
  $results[$key]['id'] = $category['id'];
  $results[$key]['headline'] = $category['title'];
  $results[$key]['content'] = is_array($category['text']) && count($category['text'])>0 ? $category['text'] : false;
  $results[$key]['metaKeywords'] = is_array($category['keywords']) && count($category['keywords'])>0 ? $category['keywords'] : false;
  $results[$key]['metaDescription'] = is_array($category['description']) && count($category['description'])>0 ? $category['description'] : false;
  $results[$key]=array_filter($results[$key]);
}
print_r($results);
```