# foreach loop over SimpleXMLElement not working, only 1 element as result

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have xml file with this structure:

```
$xmlString = '
  <plist>
    <categories>
      <category>
        <id>1</id>
        <parent>0</parent>
        <description><![CDATA[Test 1]]></description>
      </category>
      <category>
        <id>2</id>
        <parent>1</parent>
        <description><![CDATA[Test 1.1]]></description>
      </category>
      <category>
        <id>3</id>
        <parent>1</parent>
        <description><![CDATA[Test 1.2]]></description>
      </category>
      </categories>
  </plist>';
```

Now I'm trying to build an array this way:

```
$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$results = [];

foreach($xmlData->categories->category as $key => $category){
  $results[$key]['id']       = isset($category->id) ? (string)$category->id : false;
  $results[$key]['parentId'] = isset($category->parent) ? (string)$category->parent : false;
  $results[$key]['name']     = isset($category->description) ? (string)$category->description : false;
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($results,true).'</pre>';
```

But the result is only the last entry:

```
Array
(
  [category] => Array
    (
      [id] => 3
      [parentId] => 1
      [name] => Test 1.2
    )

)
```

The SimpleXMLElement Object looks like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [categories] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
      [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [parent] => 0
                    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [parent] => 1
                    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [parent] => 1
                    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                  )

            )

      )

)
```

So category is an array and i don't understand why the foreach loop isn't working. The key Should be 1,2,3 or not?

Answer (score 8):

Replace you loop with this. `$key` was always a single and same key. so it was over-writting everytime

```
$counter=0;

foreach($xmlData->categories->category as $category){
  $results[$counter]['id']       = isset($category->id) ? (string)$category->id : false;
  $results[$counter]['parentId'] = isset($category->parent) ? (string)$category->parent : false;
  $results[$counter]['name']     = isset($category->description) ? (string)$category->description : false;
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: This is redundant. Using simple `[]` has the same effect

Comment: If i use `[]` then i have to send all the `id`, `parentId` and `name` in one array.

Comment: @u_mulder: thats wrong, it will genereate an entry for every value.

Comment: @emjay Then I created an aswer for you.

Comment: To explain why this is the case: part of the magic over-ride in SimpleXML is that `foreach` returns the *element name* as the key; this is useful when doing things like `foreach ( $foo->children() as $element_name => $element )`, but less so when you're looping over a bunch of elements all with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's an answer without counters but with simple `[]`:

```
foreach($xmlData->categories->category as $category){
    $results[] = array(
        'id' => isset($category->id) ? (string)$category->id : false,
        'parentId' => isset($category->parent) ? (string)$category->parent : false,
        'name' => isset($category->description) ? (string)$category->description : false,
    );
}
```

Comment: @u_mulder thats what i was saying, in my comment

Comment: @u_mulder: what would you prefer? Using a counter, or [] ?

Comment: @SahilGulati I understand, but as OP told me `it will genereate an entry for every value` I decided to enlighten a bit.

Comment: @u_mulder Okay got it.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
$results = [];
$ii = 0;
foreach($xmlData->categories->category as $category){
$results[$ii]['id']       = isset($category->id) ? (string)$category->id : false;
$results[$ii]['parentId'] = isset($category->parent) ? (string)$category->parent : false;
$results[$ii]['name']     = isset($category->description) ? (string)$category->description : false;
$ii++;
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($results,true).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$xmlString = '
  <plist>
    <categories>
      <category>
        <id>1</id>
        <parent>0</parent>
        <description><![CDATA[Test 1]]></description>
      </category>
      <category>
        <id>2</id>
        <parent>1</parent>
        <description><![CDATA[Test 1.1]]></description>
      </category>
      <category>
        <id>3</id>
        <parent>1</parent>
        <description><![CDATA[Test 1.2]]></description>
      </category>
      </categories>
  </plist>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$json = json_encode($xml);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
// print_r($data);
$result = array();

if(isset($data['categories']['category'])) {
    foreach($data['categories']['category'] as $array){
        // print_r($array);
        $result[] = $array;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [description] => Test 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 1
            [description] => Test 1.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 1
            [description] => Test 1.2
        )

)
```

Comment: This hack always makes me sad. All you'll achieve by mangling the SimpleXML object in this way is to store up more problems for yourself later, because this is not how SimpleXML is designed to work. It's much cleaner to use SimpleXML as intended, loop over the elements, and extract the data you want, as shown in other answers.

Comment: I didn't face any problem since i am using it. So what is the problem it that.

Comment: It will not work with any XML which uses namespaces; it will not work with any element which has both text content and child nodes, or both text content and attributes; or a comment alongside any of the above; it will produce different results if there is only one item in the list, whereas SimpleXML itself will still let you loop over; it stops you using features such as XPath... And most of the time, you'll end up looping over the result and extracting a few pieces of data anyway, which you could do just as easily without doing the conversion in the first place.

Comment: Then you didn't work on that. I am playing with domx path query from last one year.And I didn't  feel any problem. I don't why you have problem. This make me sad.

Comment: I have tested this code and it works fine, as long as the XML being used is simple and small, I don't see any issue in using this code. The cases pointed by IMsOP above will only come into play if the XML being processed has all those characteristics, but for a simple XML like the one posted above, this should do the job fine! Thanks Gaurav!

Comment: Some of those cases are rare, certainly, but the single-element list case comes up for even simple XML; in fact, the code in this answer will break if there's only one `<category>` in the list: https://3v4l.org/cHSsn Whereas writing basically the same code but without the JSON hack works fine: https://3v4l.org/o8pLQ